# How to send a notification from php to android app on a specific time (schedule time)?

Tags: php, android, mysql

**notification on schedule time**

i'm trying to send a notification from php to android app. In php i create a notification and send it to app that is working perfectly.

Now i want to send the notification on specific time. but i have no idea how to do that. this notification is send threw jar file (basically it is pick up from database and send to the GSM). But really i have no idea what to do in it.

Someone help on this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Cron tasks for execution php script at specific time.

Read: [How to set Cron](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/scheduling-tasks-with-cron-jobs--net-8800)

UPD

You can try to use php [Event::addTimer](http://php.net/manual/en/event.addtimer.php) but I`m not sure it will work good if you have a lot of events.

Comment: thanks for reply.. I want to ask you if data save in mysql and suppose i start jar file all data is sending before specific time directly, so how to deal with it.

Comment: @HIREN, please clarify when exactly notification should be sent

Comment: The time i decide when i create notification i input time manually.. it is working ?. it is possible.

Comment: it is possible when i create notification that time i decide at wht time it will be send otherwise can i fix the time at what time it will be sent?  eg.  after 5hours from creating notification.